# Removing lagging latency during continuous period of drawing in ios 8.4 using swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, multi-touch

In this code i am facing the lagging problem and High CPU usage. i have created three diff file.

1. First one DrawView.swift

   ```
   class DrawView: UIView {

   var lines: [Line] = []
   var firstPoint: CGPoint!
   var percentageOfXY:[String]=[]
   var viewWidth:CGFloat!
   var viewHeight:CGFloat!
   var drawColor:UIColor!

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

       viewWidth = frame.width
       viewHeight = frame.height
       let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
       let start = touch!.locationInView(self)
       let percentageX = round(((start.x)*100)/viewWidth*100)/100
       let percentageY = round(((start.y)*100)/viewHeight*100)/100
       firstPoint = CGPointMake(percentageX, percentageY)
   }
   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

       viewWidth = frame.width
       viewHeight = frame.height
       let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
       let curr = touch!.locationInView(self)
       let percentageX = round(((curr.x)*100)/viewWidth*100)/100
       let percentageY = round(((curr.y)*100)/viewHeight*100)/100
       let lastPoint = CGPointMake(percentageX, percentageY)
       lines.append(Line(start: firstPoint, end: lastPoint, color: drawColor))
       firstPoint = lastPoint
       self.setNeedsDisplay()

   }
   override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
   {

   }
   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

       for line in lines
       {
           let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
           CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
           CGContextSetLineWidth(context,3)
           let startX = ((line.start.x)*viewWidth)/100
           let startY = ((line.start.y)*viewHeight)/100
           let endX = ((line.end.x)*viewWidth)/100
           let endY = ((line.end.y)*viewHeight)/100
           CGContextBeginPath(context)
           CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startX,startY)

           CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endX,endY)
           CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,line.color.CGColor)
           CGContextStrokePath(context)

       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Second Line.swift for storing cordinates in formats.

   ```
   class Line 
   {
   var start: CGPoint!
   var end: CGPoint!
   var cord: [String]!
   var color:UIColor!
   init(start _start: CGPoint,end _end: CGPoint,color _color:UIColor)
   {
       start = _start
       end = _end
       color = _color
   }
   }
   ```
3. Third one for color selection.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var drawView: DrawView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   }

   @IBAction func redColor(sender: AnyObject) {
       let theDrawView = drawView as DrawView
       var color:UIColor!
       color = UIColor.redColor()
       theDrawView.drawColor = color
   }
   @IBAction func greenColor(sender: AnyObject) {
       let theDrawView = drawView as DrawView
       var color:UIColor!
       color = UIColor.greenColor()
       theDrawView.drawColor = color
   }
   @IBAction func blueColor(sender: AnyObject) {
       let theDrawView = drawView as DrawView
       var color:UIColor!
       color = UIColor.blueColor()
       theDrawView.drawColor = color
   }
   ```

In this i am drawing round but through lagging problem it's draw straight line.

Comment: Since when can swift be compiled for iOS 4? Are even all depricated APIs available?

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Lucky Aroma please use the edit button and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- Get UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext out of your loop.
- Get CGContextSetLineCap out of your loop.
- Get CGContextSetLineWidth out of your loop.
- Kill CGContextBeginPath altogether--CGContextStrokePath does that for you.
- You should invent a line object with an array of points so that you don't have to keep setting the color for every little segment. TouchesBegan..TouchesEnded would start and finish one of these line objects. (You'd have to be more careful if you allow multitouch, but it doesn't look like you do.)
- If you fix the line object like above, you'd have a pair of nested loops. Then you would move the CGContextMoveToPoint out front of the inner loop and the CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor and CGContextStrokePath out of the end of the inner loop.

But now to your real problem: moving your finger across the screen can easily give several thousand pixel crossings per second. Your touchesMoved is only getting called 60 times per second (more often on an iPad Pro). If you want your sketch to look smooth, you'll have to "make up" data that was never delivered. See for example Kochanek–Bartels or Catmull–Rom splines on wikipedia.

Comment: The other thing you need to be careful of is to filter nearby touches. Fingers are fat and when the touch is moving slowly you'll get a lot of jitter if you accept every movement. I'll also ask you to consider accepting or up-voting my answer as I'd like to be able to comment on more than just my answers.

Comment: @Lucky if you want people to respond to your questions in the future, you should try to be somewhat responsive to the answers they provide.